# Why do some coding guidelines change the order of conditions in PHPs if/else?

Tags: php, coding-style

Some coding guidelines state that you should put the variable you are testing at the end of the condition:

```
// Incorrect
if($isSomething === FALSE) { // Do something }

// Correct
if(FALSE === $isSomething) { // Do something }
```

I know that some programmers have the bad habit to initalize variables in conditions like that:

```
if($results = $db->getResults() { // Do something if results exist }
```

So the only reason I could imagine for having this counterintuitive rule is to prevent wrong reinitalisation in case you accidentally use just one equal sign (=) instead of two in PHP.

Are there any other reasons?

Comment: That's pretty much the only reason for it.

Comment: I repeat after @KemalFadillah, that's the only reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not accidentally assign a value in the case you wanted to compare.
This makes finding small errors much easier.

`if (FALSE = $isSomething)` will throw an error, as you can not reassign constants
wheras
`if ($isSomething = FALSE)` will always return true and you will probably not notice that error for a long time.

Comment: Yeah... I'm pretty sure the OP knows that already. In fact, he's asking for another reason other than that.

Comment: As you already correctly stated in your other comment, there are none ;). But it makes life so much easier, so I thought I would point it out explicitly.